# Generate random numbers in a table

Tags: excel, random, vba

I want to generate random numbers in a table that goes from row 14 to 1013 and from column B to C and from columns E to QR. I have this code:

```
    Sub GenerateRandom()
      Dim i As Long
      For i = 14 To 1013
        Range("B" & i) = Rnd()
        Range("C" & i) = Rnd()
        Range("E" & i) = Rnd()
        Range("F" & i) = Rnd()
        Range("G" & i) = Rnd()
        Range("H" & i) = Rnd()
      Next i
      Randomize
    End Sub
```

And I would have to write `Range(" " & i)=RND()` each time until row QR. I would like to know a quick and easy way to do these.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here you go:

```
Sub Mariana()
    RandomValues [b14:c1013]
    RandomValues [e14:qr1013]
End Sub

Sub RandomValues(r As Range)
    r.Formula = "=rand()"
    r.Value = r.Value
End Sub
```

Note: no looping and no copying.